# Correctly ordering items for dense rank in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, dense-rank

I've tried various options (and searched around), but I simply cannot replicate this SQL functionality in R.

This is an example of my dataframe and the issue I'm trying to solve:

```
tbl <- read.table(text=
    "primaryid secondaryid date 
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1002 20180102
    2 2001 20180101
    2 2003 20180102
    2 2002 20180203" ,
    header=TRUE)
```

What I would like the function to do is to `dense_rank` the secondaryID by date appearance within the primaryid grouping, so the correct output should be:

```
primaryid   secondaryid date        sessionNumber
1           1001        20180101    1
1           1001        20180101    1
1           1002        20180102    2
2           2001        20180101    1
2           2003        20180102    **2**
2           2002        20180103    **3**
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
tbl %>%        
    arrange(primaryid, date) %>%
    group_by(primaryid) %>%
    mutate(sessionNumber=dense_rank(secondaryid))
```

but what I get is the data rank-sorted by the secondaryid column, NOT the date.

```
primaryid   secondaryid date        sessionNumber
1           1001        20180101    1
1           1001        20180101    1
1           1002        20180102    2
2           2001        20180101    1
2           2003        20180102    **3**
2           2002        20180103    **2**
```

If I were simply to use something like row_number() then this would simply inherit the arrange order, but with dense_rank you have to specify an 'x'. How should I be using dense_rank() here?

Thanks.

*edit*
to clarify the question below, if a secondaryID has two dates, then ranking on date splits them (undesired), e.g.

```
tbl <- read.table(text=
    "primaryid secondaryid date 
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1002 20180102
    2 2001 20180101
    2 2003 20180102
    2 2002 20180103
    2 2004 20180103
    2 2004 20180204" ,
    header=TRUE)

tbl %>%        
    arrange(primaryid, date) %>%
    group_by(primaryid) %>%
    mutate(sessionNumber=dense_rank(date))
```

gives;

```
 primaryid secondaryid     date sessionNumber
      <int>       <int>    <int>         <int>
1         1        1001 20180101             1
2         1        1001 20180101             1
3         1        1002 20180102             2
4         2        2001 20180101             1
5         2        2003 20180102             2
6         2        2002 20180103             3
7         2        2004 20180103             **3**
8         2        2004 20180204             **4**
```

but should give:

```
 primaryid secondaryid     date sessionNumber
      <int>       <int>    <int>         <int>
1         1        1001 20180101             1
2         1        1001 20180101             1
3         1        1002 20180102             2
4         2        2001 20180101             1
5         2        2003 20180102             2
6         2        2002 20180103             3
7         2        2004 20180103             **4**
8         2        2004 20180204             **4**
```

Comment: confused.  Why is `dense_rank(date)` not what you want?

Comment: Because there's no guarantee that a secondaryid couldn't span two dates, e.g. tbl <- read.table(text=
    "primaryid secondaryid date 
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1001 20180101
    1 1002 20180102
    2 2001 20180101
    2 2003 20180102
    2 2002 20180103
    2 2004 20180103
    2 2004 20180204" ,
    header=TRUE)  whereupon it splits the rank between the secondaryid (apologies, can't get the additional lines in here to form a table correctly)

Comment: But 2002 does span two dates, yet replacing `dense_rank(secondaryid)` with `dense_rank(date)` in your example code does give the expected output.  Can you edit the question to provide some example data in which this fails, together with the expected output for the new data.

Comment: 2002 doesn't span two dates? Anyway, I've happily added some extra examples where a date is split. I wonder whether I need to pre-process the table to find "first" date by the secondaryid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've not answered my question, but I have solved it differently.

I aggregated my data across Primary and Secondary ID, taking the minimum of Date.
I then ordered the data by Primary ID and Date.
I then applied a row_number() function against it, which works on the ordering you present and does not require a column to be specified (where I was having difficulties).
I then joined this sub-table back to my original table.

A work-around for sure. It's a shame there's no "dense" option for ranking or rownumber in the dplyr package.